# Array of two datatypes and how to change it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const AssetSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name value is required'],
    unique: true
  },
  past:[[Number], Date]
});
```

I'm trying to save an array which holds another array of numbers and a date with each array. Is this doable or not so much?

I'm updating the array with this:

```
assets[i].past.push([12,24], new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
```

But I get the error:

```
CastError: Cast to [number] failed for value "["2017-07-06T18:15:23.631Z"]" at path "past"
```

Thanks for the help, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaken, but I don't think you can do `past:[[Number], Date]`. Mongoose doesn't seem to understand it as it says in the error `Cast to [number]`

Why not be more explicit and use an array of objects instead?

```
path: [{
    numbers: [Number],
    date: Date
}]
```

which is an array of objects where each object contains an array of numbers and a date.

```
assets[i].past.push({ 
    numbers: [12,24], 
    date: new Date(Date.now()) // I don't think you need to use .toISOString()
});
```